# How to secure a Laravel API web with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I will like to secure Laravel API web with Vuejs (SPA). For example, token sent from Laravel backend to Frontend - Vuejs should be protected or can't be modified by any harmful attacks. Can anyone please guide me to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try googling exact same topic because what you asking is a too broad to answer here.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport

Comment: Yes I have but one thing that I am concerned about is that some horrible hackers may be able to access and decrypt the token and send it as a victim. What I want exactly is that I want the token to be encrypted so that these hackers can't decrypt the token. Should I proceed with using Laravel Passport or JWT? Any suggestions?

Comment: Passport tokens should be already well protected. Make sure you're using HTTPS on the site and stop panicking.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport
Laravel Passsword will help you with token, if you dont have Authentication than make your own token.

Comment: Alright I hear. thanks